# Reset/remove kubeconfig file user from Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, amazon-eks, kubeconfig, kubernetes-rbac

Whenever you start a Kubernetes cluster at one of the big clouds (EKS at AWS, GKE at GCP, AKS at Azure, or Kubernetes at Digitalocean), you can generate a kubeconfig file from them, which grants you full access.

It is now very nice to work with them, but I am always concerned about what I can do if someone manages to steal it. What can I do then?

I never found a button at one of the big clouds to revoke access of the stolen kubeconfig and to regenerate a new one. Is there anything with which I can make that aspect more secure - if you have a documentation at hand, that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In GKE at GCP the Kubeconfig file which is generated while the cluster creation is located in **$HOME/.kube/config**. The kubeconfig directory is default to $HOME/.kube/config where **$HOME** refers to the /home/.

**1.** If you want to remove user from kubeconfig file use the following command:

`$ kubectl --kubeconfig=<kubeconfig-name> config unset users.<name>`

**2.** If you want to regenerate the Kubeconfig file with the previous Kubeconfig file contents try authorizing the cluster using the command:

`$ gcloud container clusters get-credentials <cluster-name> --zone <zone> --project <project-id>`

**3.** If you want to restrict users to kubeconfig file, add permissions to kubeconfig file using the following permission commands:

`$ chmod 644 <kubeconfig-file>`  - which means that the owner can read and write the file, and all others on the system can only read it.

`$ chmod 640 <kubeconfig-file>` - that the owner has read and write permissions, the group has read permissions, and all other users have no rights to the file.

`$ chmod 600 <kubeconfig-file>` - only the owner of the file has full read and write access to it. Once a file permission is set to **600**, no one else can access the file.

**NOTE:** Revoking the contents of Kubeconfig file after the kubeconfig file deletion is not possible, you can regenerate the contents of Kubeconfig file only by authorizing the cluster.

Refer to the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/#define-clusters-users-and-contexts) for more information.